# Chris Banes -PullToRefreshListView blocks onTouch event of parent activity

Tags: android

I have implemented PullToRefreshListView in one fragment.Now the activity which contains this fragment has its onTouch event.But if the touch is on PullToRefreshListView , the onTouch event of activity is not being called.How do i call Activity's onTouch if the touch event is not meant for PullToRefreshListView.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: i am also having same issue how to fix it ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `onTouch()` method in `PullToRefreshBase` class to your own needs. Your activity will handle this event if `onTouch()` method will return `false`.